# What's the simplest query I can run within my Spring app to test my database connection?

Tags: spring

Based on my current understanding, which may be incorrect, I understand that I can set some properties in my `application.properties` file, i.e. `spring.datasource.[url|username|password]`, and that's the minimum I would need.

At this point, I would now like to do a simple query on the database to test that it can connect, like a simple `SELECT * FROM foobars` or something. What's the simplest way for me to connect to the database and run a simple test query?

Comment: If it can't connect, you'll have an error at startup. No need to execute a query. But if you really want to test that your connection is alid (although the connection pool should already do that for you), https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid(int)

Comment: How do I retrieve a Connection object?

Comment: By injecting the DataSource and calling getConnection() on it.